# How to listen to a signal from the initalItem in Stackview QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I want to listen to  a signal emitted from the `initialItem` in QML `StackView`. And it seems that the way i think on how to do it is wrong.

```
StackView {
    id: stackView
    initialItem:{
            myHomeForm{
               onMySignal{
                myArray=signalArray
               }
            }
    }
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

The documentation only says on how to set a property but none on listening to a signal
Please help thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the connection in `Component.onCompleted` through [`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals):

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Stack")

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: Page {
            id: page
            anchors.fill: parent
            signal mySignal()
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Click me")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                onClicked: page.mySignal()
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent
        Component.onCompleted: initialItem.mySignal.connect(onMySignal)
        function onMySignal(){
            console.log("onMySignal")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for future readers. If the signal has attached data the function will be written like this         `function onMySignal(data){
            console.log("onMySignal " + data)
        }`

Comment: may i followup a question sir? how would you do it if the object came from `stackview.push()`?? i understand now the syntax but how would i know that the component of the push is completed so i can then connect it afterwards?